# What are examples of functions with these property?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Complex Analysis - Silverman p. 121

> Exercise 4 (a)
>
> Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.
>
> Construct a complex valued function such that $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=0$ along curves $y=rx^k $ where $(k=0,1,\cdots,n-1)$, but $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)\neq 0$ along $y=rx^n$.

=

> Exercise 4(b)
>
> Construct a function $f$ such that $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=0$ along each curve of the form $y=mx^n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, but $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=0$ does not exist.

I completely don't know how to construct these functions.

What's the basic idea? and what are these functions?

Comment: The example in part (a) you might have seen in multivariable calculus (replacing $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $\mathbb{C}$). Also, where is $r$ used?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Edited. I don't remember any of them.. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Ok. Consider the function
$$\frac{rx^{n}}{y}.$$

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh That works for a particular $n$, not all of them.

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof I was only providing an answer to part (a) in which $n$ is fixed. I haven't thought of an example to part (b) yet.

Comment: For part (b), take the function
$$\frac{y^{2}}{x}.$$